# how can we import data from xls to SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server

I have done few searches on web and management studio was an easy option.
However i can not use management studio as this is not allowed in our project.

i am looking for a procedure or any other technique to import the data.

one of the option is Use OPENROWSET command.

any more suggestion, please?

Comment: Pl/SQL is the Oracle SQL, is your tag correct? You mentioned SQL Server, which normally refers the Microsoft DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If your question belongs to MS SQL Server I would export the excel to csv and import this file via bulk insert. This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link, it has a step by step method on importing of excel.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-Import-Excel-Sheet-data-into-SQL-Server-using-ASPNet.aspx